# Search bar remains open with empty result

Tags: javascript

When i type something and then delete it the search bar remains open with no result, even if i click on something else in the same page, how can i make it to auto-close itself after i click somewere else on the screen?

```
    SearchBx.onkeyup = (e)=>{
  let userData = e.target.value;
  let emptyArray = [];
  if(userData){
    emptyArray = suggestions.filter((data)=>{
      return data.toLocaleLowerCase().startsWith(userData.toLocaleLowerCase());
    });
    emptyArray = emptyArray.map((data)=>{
      return data = '<li>'+ data + '</li>';
    });
    console.log(emptyArray);
    Main.classList.add("show");
  }else{

  }
  showSuggestions(emptyArray);
  let allList = AutoBox.querySelectorAll("li");
  // for (let i = 0; i < allList.length; i++) {
  //   allList[i].setAttribute("onclick", "select(this)");
  // }
  for(const el of allList){ // use for..of instead of indexed for
    el.addEventListener('click', (e) => { // attach an event listener instead of using the onclick attribute
      SearchBx.value = e.target.textContent; // can be a separate function like 'select', but whatever 
      ouvrirPage(); // trigger page opening from click event
    }); 
  }
}
// function select(element){
//   let selectUserData = element.textContent;
//   SearchBx.value = selectUserData;
// }
function showSuggestions(list){
  let listData;
  if(!list.length){
    userValue = SearchBx.value;
    listData = '<li>'+ userValue +'</li>'
  }else{
    listData = list.join('');
  }
  AutoBox.innerHTML = listData;
}
```

https://codepen.io/galusk0149007/pen/NWXEVmO

Comment: Please do not use the "java" tag for Javascript. Java and Javascript are about as related as Austria and Australia.

Answer (score 1):

Add one `onblur` event to your search bar and remove the `.show` class from the `search-bar`

something like the below:

```js
SearchBx.onblur = () => {
  Main.classList.remove('show');
}
```

Since the above solution closes the dropdown on selecting, here is another working solution -

Select your wrapper element and add an event to remove the `show` class when clicking on it.

```js
let wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');

wrapper.onclick = () => {
  Main.classList.remove('show');
}
```

Comment: this kinda works but then the selection stops working, if you try to search something

Comment: Check the above answer, i have modified it.

Comment: still not working as it should :( the search icon does not work anymore

Answer (score 1):

the solution to my problem was adding this

```
SearchBx.onclick = () => {
  Main.classList.remove('show');
}
```

Comment: Better option: by adding id "body" in the body of the html page, and adding let Body = document.getElementById("body"); in java then i can use body.onclick = () => {
  Main.classList.remove('show');} wich works the best